# Multiple Inputs/Outputs from Execute R Script

Tags: r, azure-machine-learning-service

Assume I have an Execute R Script that calculates multiple variables, say X and Y.
Is it possible to save X as a dataset ds_X and Y as a dataset ds_Y?

The problem is that there is only 1 output port available that needs to be mapped to a data.frame. Am I missing an option to add more output ports?
Same problem for input ports. I may connect 2 of the "Enter Data Manually" modules to it, but what if I need 3? The current workaround is to put CSV files in a ZIP file and connect that. Are there easier solution?

**Example of what i tried:**

I tried adding ds_X and ds_Y to a list. The idea is to pass this list to multiple "Execute R Script" modules and use the required list elements there.
Mapping a list to an output port does not seem to work though:

```
# Calculate lots of stuff - results are ds_X and ds_Y
ds_X <- mtcars
ds_Y <- cars
out <- list(ds_X, ds_Y)

maml.mapOutputPort("out")
```

results in an error:

```
Error: Mapped variable must be of class type data.frame at this time.
```

Comment: One option, if I understand correctly, is to save your variables out globally, i.e. using `<<-`, or you could set your output to produce a list. Save `ds_X` and `ds_Y` within the script, and then make the output `list(ds_X, ds_Y)`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I actually tried returning `list(ds_X, ds_Y)` and then having two "Execute R Script" modules process its first/second element respectively. Unfortunately, a data.frame instead of a list has to be returned though.

Comment: The output would be a data.frame: `listName <- list(ds_X, ds_Y)` and then `listName[[1]]` and `listName[[2]]` are data.frames. However, I think without an example it's tricky to say anything more.

Comment: The problem is not that the `ds_X` and `ds_Y` are no data.frames but the list in which they are contained. I added an example to my original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can author custom R Modules.

Here is some documentation: 
https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/machinelearning/2015/04/23/build-your-own-r-modules-in-azure-ml/
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/machine-learning-custom-r-modules

Comment: I will accept your answer because it works this way. Nevertheless it is cumbersome to create a new module just for adjusting the number of inputs/outputs in my opinion. Microsoft should allow parameters to the "Execute R Script" module instead.