# Multiple outputs from custom module

Tags: r, azure, azure-machine-learning-service

[This Microsoft Azure documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/azure/machine-learning/studio/custom-r-modules) shows how to author custom modules for the Azure Machine Learning Studio. There is a paragraph about returning multiple outputs from your module. Yet following the instructions I can only see data in the visualization of the first output port while the others remain empty.

This is a follow-up question to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46340959/multiple-inputs-outputs-from-execute-r-script). I accepted the answer there because I misinterpreted the result of the custom module I wrote - it is possible for some output ports to be empty and I hastily assumed the output to be correct. However, running the same code in RStudio does indeed generate data that should have been returned in ML Studio as well. Also, printing the data works.

**Minimal example:**

The source files contained in the module's ZIP file:

test.R

```
foo <- function() {
    require(data.table)
    out1 <- data.table(mtcars)
    out2 <- data.table(cars)

    print("out1:")
    print(head(out1))
    print("out2:")
    print(head(out2))

    return(list(out1, out2))
}
```

test.xml

```
<Module name="Multiple outputs">
  <Owner>...</Owner>
  <Language name="R" sourceFile="test.R" entryPoint="foo"/> 
    <Ports>
      <Output id="out_1" name="out1" type="DataTable">
        <Description>...</Description>
      </Output>
      <Output id="out_2" name="out2" type="DataTable">
        <Description>...</Description>
      </Output>   
    </Ports>
</Module>
```

Which yields this module that runs successfully:

[image: Module in Azure]

The visualizations of the output however look like this:
[image: Correct visualization of output 1]
[image: Empty visualization of output 2]

Whereas the output log looks good:

```
[ModuleOutput] [1] "out1:"
[ModuleOutput] 
[ModuleOutput]     mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
[ModuleOutput] 
[ModuleOutput] 1: 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
[ModuleOutput] 
[ModuleOutput] 2: 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
[ModuleOutput] 
[ModuleOutput] 3: 22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
[ModuleOutput] 
[ModuleOutput] 4: 21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
[ModuleOutput] 
[ModuleOutput] 5: 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
[ModuleOutput] 
[ModuleOutput] 6: 18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
[ModuleOutput] 
[ModuleOutput] [1] "out2:"
[ModuleOutput] 
[ModuleOutput]    speed dist
[ModuleOutput] 
[ModuleOutput] 1:     4    2
[ModuleOutput] 
[ModuleOutput] 2:     4   10
[ModuleOutput] 
[ModuleOutput] 3:     7    4
[ModuleOutput] 
[ModuleOutput] 4:     7   22
[ModuleOutput] 
[ModuleOutput] 5:     8   16
[ModuleOutput] 
[ModuleOutput] 6:     9   10
```

I think I followed the instructions from the documentation correctly.
Has someone encountered this problem before? Are there any known solutions?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The R output bridge expects a data frame, try this instead of data.table

```
out1 <- data.frame(mtcars)
out2 <- data.frame(cars)
```